# TypeError: create() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given) - Odoo v8 wizard

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I've created a wizard with steps, here's my xml:

```
<record id="view_wizard_prod_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">bsi.production.order.wizard</field>
    <field name="model">bsi.production.order</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Production Order">
          <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="step1,step2,step3,step4" statusbar_colors='{"step3":"blue","step4":"blue"}' clickable="True" />
              <group>
                <group>
                  <field name="date_production" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}" />
                  <field name="product_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}" />
                  <field name="qty_available" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}" />
                  <field name="isbn1" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}" />
                  <field name="isbn2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="isbn3" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="isbn4" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="isbn5" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="isbn6" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group>
                  <field name="type_prod" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step1')]}"/>
                  <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}" />
                  <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                  <field name="print_order2" attrs="{'invisible': [('type_prod', '!=', 'direct')]}"/>
                </group>
            </group>
            <group>
                <group string="Book Block" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}">
                        <field name="name_block" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="category" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="language" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="edition" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="book_block_textp" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="n_pages_one_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="two_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="four_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="total" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="text_print_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="book_block_adpaper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="adnl_n_pages_one_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="adnl_two_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="adnl_third_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="adnl_four_color" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="adnl_total" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="adnl_text_print_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="book_block_txtep" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="n_of_end_pages" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Book Size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}">
                        <field name="name_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="description_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="forme_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                        <field name="plate_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step2')]}"/>
                </group>
            </group>
            <group>
                <group string="Book Edition" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                        <field name="name_edition" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Book Binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                        <field name="name_binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Cut Off" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                        <field name="name_cut" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="description_cut" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="cutoff_size" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Paper Master" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}">
                        <field name="name_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="description_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="paper_type" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="uom_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="gsm_papermaster" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="std_cost_rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="qty_in_kgs" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="size_width" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                        <field name="size_height" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step3')]}"/>
                </group>
            </group>
            <group>
                <group string="End Paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                        <field name="name_end_paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="category_end_paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="size_end_paper" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Printing Code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                        <field name="description_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="size_code" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Book Edge" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                        <field name="name_book_edge" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                </group>
                <group string="Job Rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}">
                        <field name="name_jobrate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="binding" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="size_binding_job_rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="bind_variety" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="rates" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="addl_rate" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                        <field name="uptoforme" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
                </group>
            </group>
    </form>
     <footer>
       <button string="Save" name="save_data" type="object" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '!=', 'step4')]}"/>
     </footer>
    </field>
</record>
```

And this is the method for button `save_data`:

```
@api.multi
def save_data(self):
    imd = self.env['ir.model.data']
    self.name = name
    return (bsi_production_order, self).create(self)
```

I'm just adding one field, for the example, regardless of the fields needed it always throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 8.0-20170809\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
TypeError: create() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)
```

I've tried  in many ways, looked at different examples, but no success, any ideas?

**EDIT**

I've also tried like this:

```
@api.multi
def save_data(self, vals):
    vals = {
        'name' : name,
    }
    return (bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)
```

Same error... I'm really stuck unto this

Comment: Can you try and explain what are you doing? When is method save_data called and what should it do? What is bsi_production_order?

Comment: Hi, on the wizard view xml there is the object button calling ´save_data´, this is a step by step wizard, it is actually to create a new record on table, but on a step by step fashion, instead of a traditional  form view. And ´bsi_production_order´ is the table's name, the object which I want to create records upon, this exists already as a form, the step by step wizard is complete, the only thing left is to save these records with ´save_data´ method in this case.

Comment: You said  ´bsi_production_order´ is table's name, but in your code you have variable bsi_production_order. Is this variable string that contains table's name? I am asking you this because I am trying to understand what is this line doing `(bsi_production_order, self).create(self)`.

Comment: Also is this hole Traceback (Error info) that you got. Is there Traceback that starts from code in your program (python script) so we can know what triggers the problem?

Comment: Yes, it contains table's name, this is from Odoo orm new api, it is actually an Odoo module, that is all the traceback... :(, it is not "pure" python if that's what You expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call create like that use this.

```
        self.env['your.model.name'].create(vals)
```

And if you override the create method in odoo 10 for example.

```
             @api.model
              def create(self, values) :
                      # your code here
```

Comment: Actually, as I told @JuanSalcedo it was my fault, but also, this solved another issue that arose after I solved my original dumb problem, Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

**create** method receive a dict as parameter and you should call in this way `self.create(vals)` if you already being in the model that you want create for, if you are not, you should call create method with *super* something like this `super(class_name, self).create(vals)`,  *vals* it's the dict.

EDIT:

The definition of **create** method is:

```
def create(self, vals):
```

you could see in this [link](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ff30928786961efef66706729286e7f48c754bbd/openerp/models.py#L4058), as you can see it reviced two parameters *(self, vals)*, when you call this method(i.e *`super(class_name, self).create(vals)`*) **self** is implicit, like passed 'self' thats why you get the error *TypeError: **create() takes exactly 2** arguments (5 given)* 'couse self contains: cr, uid, ids ...

I hope this little explanation could help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but actually I've tried something like that before, I've edited my question, if You want to check it out, still same error :/

Comment: I think it has something to do with new API, that ´vals´ way I've used is kind of "old school"

Comment: lol, I'm sorry, it was an error of mine, I had some other test method I didn't remove, thank You